# Alternative to paper towels for draining fried food?

Tags: food, paper, alternatives

When frying food, what's a good alternative to paper towels for soaking up/draining excess oil?

Comment: We prefer to use lightly woven undyed cloth.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Personally I use a wire rack over a cookie sheet to drain fried or greasy foods. The oil drips to the pan below and I can pour the oil into a container or dispose of it however I need to.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use wire cooling racks, brown paper bags, and cloth dishtowels dedicated to this endeavor would work for draining. Paper towels you do use might be compostable.

Comment: Composting the oil-soaked paper towels will be more complicated, yes?

Comment: @LShaver small amounts of oil compost without problems, so it's fine for occasional use, but rather less so if this is a daily habit.  Even then, dripping off as much as possible for reuse, before using paper to soak up the last bits will help

Answer (score 5):

I have not found much of an alternative to paper towels, but you could at least try the following:

1. Drain food that has been deep fried on a wire rack. Only after this use paper towel to soak up excess oil.
2. I keep paper towel that is soaked in cooking oil and use it as a fire-lighter later on. Of course, that only works if you have a wood-fired stored.
3. To minimise the use of paper towels in cleaning, I make use of our local food waste scheme, which accepts cooked food. For greasy pans: used teabags, or vegetable peelings that seem to be sufficiently absorbent, are used to wipe the pans before washing them. I then compost the oily teabags This saves a large amount of detergent and water.

Comment: Storing the paper towels also requires a fireproof storage container: oily rags are notorious for spontaneously combusting.

Comment: @Mark that depends on the oil.  The spontaneously combusting oily rags are those soaked in linseed oil, which oxidises and polymerises rather quickly (that's what makes it a good wood treatment), releasing heat.  Common cooking oils don't behave like this, though I'd still use a glass or metal container with a closed lid, on a surface that's not easily damaged by spilt oil or heat.  Incidentally I've tried to get linseed oil soaked cotton rags to spontaneously ignite (well contained with concrete bricks or a metal bucket), and haven't succeeded

Answer (score 3):

Not a 100% alternative, but a reduction:
Use only **one layer** of paper towel and used newspapers under it.

Comment: @ Jan Doggen, newspapers contain carbon and chemicals that trigger cancer. Even if underneath, it may be risky.

Comment: That is the way we do it at home. But think I will check out J. Chomels answer

Answer (score 3):

Slices of stale bread are a good alternative. I keep crusts / the ends of loaves in the freezer and place 4 to 6 on a tray to cover the tray. You then just place your fried food on top to drain. The bread is fine to go in the compost afterwards.

Comment: If there's too much oil in the bread, won't this make composting more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Use woven/organic undyed cloth piece, and then wash it along with other clothes. Keep this piece only for draining food.

Example: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Reusable-Organic-Cheesecloth-ColorGrown-Ubleached/dp/B07622VQVM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07622VQVM)

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but it would seem hand washing might be better -- depending on how oily the cloth is, it could take a lot more soap or stain the other clothing you're washing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the salad spinner is not a bad idea at all. It will require washing up after - detergent/water/time costs. Whereas the cloth /tea towel is pretty simple.

On the rare occasion I fry anything that needs draining I just let it drain on a warm or even hot plate. The heat will keep the oil flowing and the food warm, cold will congeal oil and cool the food.

I degrease pans etc. with old teabags or newspaper before washing. It really helps cut down detergent and washing time. We Brits always have teabags about.

Answer (score 1):

My company Green City Living addressed this in 2014 when I invented the Bacon Sponge.  It’s an absorbent towel that releases the grease when soaked in hot water and a degreaser soap like Mrs Meyer or Dawn for 15 minutes.  Then it can be washed in the laundry with towels.   It’s 100% cotton and  biodegradable.  https://greencityliving.earth/products/bacon-sponge-unpaper-towel-for-grease

Comment: Hi Kathy, thanks for sharing and welcome to the site! This answer is a reasonable use of [self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/137452) because it's directly relevant to the question and you disclosed your affiliation up-front. I look forward to seeing more questions and answers from you here. :-)

Answer (score -2):

I have no clue at all if this would work or if it would damage the plastic possibly yes but if you could ever find a metal one of these a Salad spinner may do the trick.  [image]

Comment: This is not an answer, this is rather a strange idea that you did not even try.